# Modeling a dependent computation task?

Tags: typescript, haskell, recursion-schemes, catamorphism

I need to model a computation task and some sub-tasks depend on it:

First I run a task, if it fails then it's over. If it succeeds then run a bunch of sub-tasks(zero or many), any of them can fail or succeed, and can run zero or many sub-sub-tasks if it succeeds. So it is roughly in Haskell:

```hs
data DepTask a b = Fail a | Success b [DepTask a b] deriving (Functor)
```

However, I am not a Haskell programmer, just find it is easier to describe my problem in Haskell.
My problem is, how could I "fold" this structure? Such as pretty-print it in Html.
ChatGPT suggests that I could define this kind of structure as fixed point, so that I can make use of cata to fold it.

```hs
data ComplexF a b next = FailF a | SuccessF b [next] deriving (Functor)
type Complex a b = Fix (ComplexF a b)
```

Is there any Haskell library (maybe also TypeScript equivalent) I can adopt?

ps: Sorry for my bad English since I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: `deriving (..., Foldable)`? Might not fulfill your needs, but you should be more specific then. What do you mean by "as pretty-print it in Html"?

Comment: Such as convert into an Html fragment with nested ol and li, and describe with "task #x succeeded" or "task #y failed, the error message is zzz"; or just display the failed tasks; or just briefly describe how many tasks succeeded/failed; or just flatten all the task and sub-tasks. Actually I do not have specific needs, I just want to record the information in a structural way, so that I may fold/display later

Comment: Well, these are rather different. Though there are tools that can accomplish all of that, the most appropriate being perhaps [uniplate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate). Though I would rather do it with [`Generic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Generic). Not sure about TypeScript though.

Comment: As much as I love `cata`s, perhaps here you could start with a solution using explicit recursion. E.g. (pseudocode) `pprint (Fail x) = use x ; pprint (Success y ts) = use y res where res = map pprint ts`. Here the key is to define `res` as the list of pretty-printed subtasks, and use that and `y` to pretty-print the successes. I'd code a basic string output first. Then you can look on hackage for HTML libraries and design your fancy output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement this in Haskell as a relatively new Haskell programmer, then it would be best to keep things simple.  If you want to identify tasks by integers and represent error messages as strings, then you can use the following simple data type to model your problem:

```haskell
data Task = Task Int (Either String [Task]) deriving (Show)
```

That is, a `Task` identified by an `Int` either fails with an error `String` or succeeds with a list of subtasks, `[Task]`.

(You could, optionally, replace the `Either` type with your own success/failure type:

```haskell
data Result = Failure String | Success [Task]
```

but the use of `Either` for this purpose, including the use of `Left` for failure and `Right` for success, is pretty well established in the Haskell world.)

Equipped with `Task`, if you want a list of failed tasks and their associated errors, just write a plain old recursive function using pattern matching:

```haskell
failures :: Task -> [(Int, String)]
failures (Task n (Left err))   = [(n, err)]
failures (Task _ (Right tsks)) = concatMap failures tsks
```

If you want a flattened list of all tasks by IDs with an associated success flag, write another plain old recursive function using pattern matching:

```haskell
flatten :: Task -> [(Int, Bool)]
flatten (Task n (Left _))    = [(n, False)]
flatten (Task n (Right tsks))  = (n, True) : concatMap flatten tsks
```

If you want to render the results as HTML, then an *ad hoc* pretty printer would look something like this:

```haskell
asHtml :: [Task] -> String
asHtml = ul ""
  where ul pfx body = pfx ++ "<ul>\n"
                          ++ concatMap (li (pfx ++ "  ")) body ++
                      pfx ++ "</ul>\n"
        li pfx (Task n result) = pfx ++ "<li>Task #" ++ show n
          ++ case result of
               Left err -> " failed, the error message is \"" ++ err ++ "\"\n"
               Right [] -> " succeeded with no subtasks\n"
               Right tsks -> " succeeded, invoking subtasks:\n" ++ ul pfx tsks
```

This will be the most straightforward approach.

After you've written 10 or 15 useful functions, you could give some consideration to "abstracting" out the common fold (AKA catamorphism), but you'll probably find it doesn't buy you much.  A fold for `Task` would look something like this:

```haskell
foldTask :: (Int -> Either String [a] -> a) -> Task -> a
foldTask f (Task n (Left err)) = f n (Left err)
foldTask f (Task n (Right tsks)) = f n (Right (map (foldTask f) tsks))
```

If you reimplement your functions in terms of this fold, they will no longer be explicitly recursive, but the result is not noticeably more concise or readable than the original:

```haskell
failures' :: Task -> [(Int, String)]
failures' = foldTask f
  where f n (Left err) = [(n, err)]
        f _ (Right tsks) = concat tsks

flatten' :: Task -> [(Int, Bool)]
flatten' = foldTask f
  where f n (Left _) = [(n, False)]
        f n (Right tsks) = (n, True) : concat tsks
```

ChatGPT's advice seems pretty stupid.  It's suggesting you reimplement
your `Task'` as a fixed point of a functor `TaskF`:

```haskell
data TaskF a = TaskF Int (Either String [a]) deriving (Functor)
data Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }
type Task' = Fix TaskF
```

so you can implement an abstract catamorphism:

```haskell
cata :: (Functor f) => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata k = k . fmap (cata k) . unFix
```

that can be used as follows:

```haskell
failures'' :: Task' -> [(Int, String)]
failures'' = cata f
  where f (TaskF n (Left err)) = [(n, err)]
        f (TaskF _ (Right tsks)) = concat tsks

flatten'' :: Task' -> [(Int, Bool)]
flatten'' = cata f
  where f (TaskF n (Left _)) = [(n, False)]
        f (TaskF n (Right tsks)) = (n, True) : concat tsks
```

This is perhaps of some theoretical interest, and there are some cool related libraries, like `recursion-schemes`, but this isn't particular useful to a new Haskell programmer implementing a simple model like this.

Anyway, here's a complete file with sample code:

```haskell
module DepTask where

--
-- Implementation for normal humans
--

data Task = Task Int (Either String [Task]) deriving (Show)

failures :: Task -> [(Int, String)]
failures (Task n (Left err))   = [(n, err)]
failures (Task _ (Right tsks)) = concatMap failures tsks

flatten :: Task -> [(Int, Bool)]
flatten (Task n (Left _))    = [(n, False)]
flatten (Task n (Right tsks))  = (n, True) : concatMap flatten tsks

asHtml :: [Task] -> String
asHtml = ul ""
  where ul pfx body = pfx ++ "<ul>\n"
                          ++ concatMap (li (pfx ++ "  ")) body ++
                      pfx ++ "</ul>\n"
        li pfx (Task n result) = pfx ++ "<li>Task #" ++ show n
          ++ case result of
               Left err -> " failed, the error message is \"" ++ err ++ "\"\n"
               Right [] -> " succeeded with no subtasks\n"
               Right tsks -> " succeeded, invoking subtasks:\n" ++ ul pfx tsks

--
-- Unnecessary abstraction of the fold
--

foldTask :: (Int -> Either String [a] -> a) -> Task -> a
foldTask f (Task n (Left err)) = f n (Left err)
foldTask f (Task n (Right tsks)) = f n (Right (map (foldTask f) tsks))

failures' :: Task -> [(Int, String)]
failures' = foldTask f
  where f n (Left err) = [(n, err)]
        f _ (Right tsks) = concat tsks

flatten' :: Task -> [(Int, Bool)]
flatten' = foldTask f
  where f n (Left _) = [(n, False)]
        f n (Right tsks) = (n, True) : concat tsks

--
-- ChatGPTs crazy advice
--

data TaskF a = TaskF Int (Either String [a]) deriving (Functor)
data Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }
type Task' = Fix TaskF

cata :: (Functor f) => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata k = k . fmap (cata k) . unFix

failures'' :: Task' -> [(Int, String)]
failures'' = cata f
  where f (TaskF n (Left err)) = [(n, err)]
        f (TaskF _ (Right tsks)) = concat tsks

flatten'' :: Task' -> [(Int, Bool)]
flatten'' = cata f
  where f (TaskF n (Left _)) = [(n, False)]
        f (TaskF n (Right tsks)) = (n, True) : concat tsks

--
-- Some examples
--

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let ex1 = [ Task 1 (Left "file not found")
            , Task 2 (Right [ Task 3 (Right [])
                            , Task 4 (Right [Task 5 (Left "bad parameter")])])
            , Task 3 (Right []) ]
  putStrLn $ asHtml ex1

  let ex2 = Task 0 (Right ex1)

  print $ failures ex2
  print $ failures' ex2

  let task n r = Fix (TaskF n r)
      ex2' = task 0 (Right
        [ task 1 (Left "file not found")
        , task 2 (Right [ task 3 (Right [])
                        , task 4 (Right [task 5 (Left "bad parameter")])])
        , task 3 (Right []) ])

  print $ failures'' ex2'
```